# ArcObjects ExportMapImage modifies image extent

Tags: arcobjects, export, image, extents

I am trying to extract a map image at a certain range. I am using IMxdServer's ExportMapImage method, documented [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000mw7000000).

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
    IMapDocumentPtr ipMapDoc(CLSID_MapDocument);
    IMapDescriptorPtr ipMapDescriptor(CLSID_MapDescriptor);
    IMxdServerPtr ipMapServer(CLSID_MxdServer);
    IArrayPtr ipArray(CLSID_Array);
    IUnknownPtr ipUnknown;
    int dpi = 300;
            IEnvelopePtr ipPixelBoundsEnv(CLSID_Envelope), ipReturnExtent(CLSID_Envelope);
    ipPixelBoundsEnv->PutCoords(mUpperLeftLong, mLowerRightLat, mLowerRightLong,  mUpperLeftLat);

    ipMapServer->Start(MxdPath);
    ipMapServer->get_MapDescriptors(&ipArray);

    ipArray->get_Element(0, &ipUnknown);
    ipMapDescriptor = (IMapDescriptorPtr) ipUnknown;

    IColorPtr ipColor(CLSID_RgbColor);
    ipMapDescriptor->get_BackgroundColor(&ipColor);
    ipMapDescriptor->put_TransparentColor(ipColor);
    ipMapDescriptor->put_Extent(ipPixelBoundsEnv);
    ipMapDescriptor->put_FullExtent(ipPixelBoundsEnv);
    ipMapDescriptor->put_KeepAspectRatio(VARIANT_FALSE);

    HRESULT hr = ipMapServer->ExportMapImage(ipMapDescriptor, dpi, (256*(hortizonalTileBlockCount+2)), (256*(verticalTileBlockCount+2)), CComBSTR("PNG8"), bstrFileLocation, &ipReturnExtent);
    double ux, uy, lx, ly;
    ipReturnExtent->get_XMax(&ux);
    ipReturnExtent->get_XMin(&lx);
    ipReturnExtent->get_YMax(&uy);
    ipReturnExtent->get_YMin(&ly);
    std::cout<<"return extent "<<lx<<","<<ly<<","<<ux<<","<<uy<< " \n";
```

In my current example the following bounds are passed in:

```
-75.9375,39.6395,-77.3438,40.714
```

The return extent is shifted a touch:

```
-77.3438,39.4736,-75.9375,40.8799
```

I'm extracting quite a few images but I put one example extent for reference.

Comment: How does the output look compared to what is expected? Are those slight differences accounted for by the fact that it is snapping the extent to values that can be represented by coordinates on discrete pixel boundaries?

Comment: the differences are bigger than that, 50-100 pixel shift upward. the image is 1024x1024 pixels. I think it has something to do with it wanting the height and width to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. The problem was that ESRI was trying to maintain the a square envelope since the map was in lat/long it wasn't square. By converting it to web mercator I was able to get the bounds just as I wanted them. The conversion looked like this:

```
    ISpatialReferenceFactoryPtr srFactory(CLSID_SpatialReferenceEnvironment);
    ISpatialReferencePtr iGoogleSRef, iLatLongSRef;
    IProjectedCoordinateSystemPtr pcs;
    IGeographicCoordinateSystemPtr gcs;
    int dpi=300;
    IEnvelopePtr ipPixelBoundsEnv(CLSID_Envelope), ipReturnExtent(CLSID_Envelope);

    //get web merc s ref
    srFactory->CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem(3857, &pcs);
    iGoogleSRef = pcs;


    srFactory->CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(4326, &gcs);
    iLatLongSRef = gcs;
    ipPixelBoundsEnv->putref_SpatialReference(iLatLongSRef);
    ipPixelBoundsEnv->PutCoords(mUpperLeftLong, mLowerRightLat, mLowerRightLong,  mUpperLeftLat);

    ipPixelBoundsEnv->Project(iGoogleSRef);
```